# Printf nasm trouble

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am in an assembly class, and I need to print out a white character "*" a bunch of times for a project I am doing. I have been sitting here for hours trying to make the printW function work, so it would be called X times. The following code will print out 2 "*"s, changing the initial cx to any number, does not change the number of "*"s the code prints. I am at my wits end. Can someone please find the issue with the code, and explain why it was an issue?

```
printBoard:
    mov ecx,0x00010
    cmp ecx,0
    loop printWhiteRow
    ret

printWhiteRow:
    call printW


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;print a string
printW:
    push ebp                ; set up stack frame
    mov ebp,esp
    mov eax, whiteChar              ; put a from store into register
    push eax                ; value of variable a
    call printf             ; Call C function
    add esp, 8              ; pop stack 3 push times 4 bytes
    mov esp, ebp            ; takedown stack frame
    pop ebp                 ; same as "leave" op
    ret                     ; return
```

Comment: Don't you need to save the `ecx` register before calling `printf()` i.e `push ecx  ; store ecx on stack call printf  ; pop ecx ; restore ecx` and why not just do `loop printW`? Notice that you **don't** need to check if `ecx` is 0 when using `loop` this way.

Comment: Also, should not `add esp, 8` be `add esp, 4` since you only pushing one argument onto the stack?

Answer (score 2):

Some issues:

1. You don't seem to know how `loop` instruction works.
2. No idea what this is supposed to mean: `add esp, 8 ; pop stack 3 push times 4 bytes`. 3 times 4 is 12, and in any case you only pushed 1 argument.
3. The cdecl calling convention defines `ecx` as caller-saved, so you need to save it if you want its value to be preserved.
4. If you want to print a single character, why not use `putchar`?

Something like this should work better:

```
printBoard:
    mov ecx,0x00010
printWhiteRow:
    push ecx     ; save counter
    push ' '     ; char to print
    call putchar
    pop ecx      ; cleanup argument
    pop ecx      ; restore counter
    loop printWhiteRow
    ret
```

Same with `printf`:

```
printBoard:
    mov ecx,0x00010
printWhiteRow:
    push ecx       ; save counter
    push whiteChar ; string to print
    call printf
    pop ecx        ; cleanup argument
    pop ecx        ; restore counter
    loop printWhiteRow
    ret
```

Comment: My professor wants us to specifically use the printf function, and the symbols should all be on the same line...

Comment: `putchar` puts them on the same line ;) Anyway, `printf` is similar.